# ToDo complete status not staying saved in storage in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

Edit - added minimally reproducible example: https://snack.expo.dev/@hdorra/code

I hope everyone can access the snack. So if you add a task, you can see it show up in the log. Click on the circle, it shows as true (meaning it is clicked). Save and refresh and everything is stored (the task) but the checkbox is not. I stripped the code to make it as bare minimum as possible but it shows the problem.

It has been days of me on this error. I am relatively new to stackoverflow so my apologies if my question isn't clear or I am not asking it in the correct format. I am trying to create a to do app in react native that is using async storage. I created a toggle button that saves the toggle to a state. This button is located in a component:

```
 const [checkBoxState, setCheckBoxState] = React.useState(false);

 const toggleComplete = () => {

        setCheckBoxState(!checkBoxState)
        handleEdit();
        console.log(checkBoxState)

    }
```

When the user checks on it - seems to be showing up correctly as marked true and false in the console.
Then, this is passed to an edit handler to update the array, again console shows it is the correct state:

```
  const handleEdit = () => {
        props.editHandler(props.todoKey, text, checkBoxState);
        console.log(text2, checkBoxState)
    };
```

Then it shows that it saved correctly:

```
 const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([]);
 const handleEdit = (todoKey, text, newStatus) => {
        const newTodos = [...todos];
        const index = newTodos.findIndex(todos => todos.key === todoKey);
        newTodos[index] = Object.assign(newTodos[index], {title: text, status: newStatus});
        setTodos(newTodos);
    
        console.log(todos, newStatus)
    };
```

The async function to save to the device and load are as follows:
To save:

```
const saveTodoToUserDevice = async (todos) => {
        try {
            const stringifyTodos = JSON.stringify(todos);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('todos', stringifyTodos);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
```

To load from the device:

```
const getTodosFromUserDevice = async () => {
        try {
            const todos = await AsyncStorage.getItem('todos');
            if (todos != null) {
                setTodos(JSON.parse(todos));
                console.log("loaded successfully");
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
```

So here is the issue - I get the console log that says it is saved correctly and loaded. BUT, when I refresh, the checkbox state is not saved at all, just the title text (so it is saving but the checkbox would always be false (the initial state set). If I clicked on true, it would show as true and then when I refresh, it goes back to false.

I have spent days and days on this and can't figure it out. Any direction would be helpful Thank you!

Comment: Welcome user15928679 ! Do we assume that this `[checkboxChecked, setCheckboxChecked=useState(false)` is typo while pasting the question here on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Oh so sorry! Yes, it is: const [checkBoxState, setCheckBoxState] = React.useState(false);

Comment: Any help would be so appreciated, I have spent DAYS and looked at every possible answer on stackoverflow. It is not rerendering, it is identifying the state (checked versus not in the array), everything else is saving but any refresh, they all go back to the baseline false. I thought maybe it had to do with it not being a string but the savetodos and gettodos functions stringify and parse accordingly.

Comment: After that `setTodos(newTodos);` in `handleEdit`, you are not calling `saveTodoToUserDevice(newTodos)`, do you?

Comment: If you could add all the relevant code to make it a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be grate. Like adding the components where you haves those specific codes you pasted. You can edit your post.

Comment: I tried that, and just tried again right now (tried so many things I forgot and wanted to double check)...no change. Any refresh at all to the screen, everything is saved except the state all goes back to default false.

Comment: Let me add it now....one moment....

Comment: Hi yousoumar I added a snack...it seems to show in the log what is going on. Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: Thanks. I pasted an answer. Take a look please and let me know in the comment section there.

Comment: Hi yousoumar, Thank you so much - it worked except for one thing - it saves when I refresh. However, when I click on edit and click back, it goes back to false. I think (and I can be completely wrong) it is because I am passing the !props.status to handledit so it reverts back to the original. In the snack, the edit button was off the screen - I fixed it. You can see in the log - when you click, it shows true, but when you click on the question mark and then back which is supposed to be the edit button, it clears out and becomes false again. Can you let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I see. I didn't realise you were using `handleEdit` in two places. To solve your last issue, see my just updated answer. So you would have two functions, `toggleStatus`  and `handleEdit` in Task.js, one for each button. Let me know in the comment section of the answer itself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have gone through your [code](https://snack.expo.dev/@hdorra/code) and found some errors you are making in different places. In `Task.js` you can do without that `checkBoxState`. For that, pass the `status` to `Task` as `props` while rendering it in `FlatList`, like so:

```
<Task
  key={item.key}
  todoKey={item.key}
  title={item.title}
  status={item.status}
  editHandler={handleEdit}
  pressHandler={handleDelete}
/>
```

Then as below, change the button to toggle the `status`, so you use what's coming from the `props` and create a function called `toggleStatus` and pass it to `onPress`:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleStatus}>
  <View
    style={[
      styles.circle,
      !props.status ? styles.completeCircle : styles.incompleteCircle,
    ]}
  ></View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

The code for `toggleStatus`:

```
const toggleStatus = () => {
  props.editHandler(props.todoKey, props.title, !props.status);
};
```

And `handleEdit` would be simplified to:

```
const handleEdit = () => {
  props.editHandler(props.todoKey, text2, props.status);
  setEdit(false);
  console.log(props.status);
};
```

Lastly, in `TasksMain.js` so you don't replace what's in the storage with that initial array given to `useState`, make sure `saveTodoToUserDevice` runs after `getTodosFromUserDevice`. For that, add the below state in `TasksMain.js` and slightly change the two functions as follow:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
```

```
const saveTodoToUserDevice = async (todos) => {
  if (loading) return;
  try {
    const stringifyTodos = JSON.stringify(todos);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("todos", stringifyTodos);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

```
const getTodosFromUserDevice = async () => {
  try {
    const todos = await AsyncStorage.getItem("todos");
    if (todos != null) {
      setTodos(JSON.parse(todos));
      console.log("loaded successfully");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};
```